# Can't add friend as developer/tester: "There was a problem getting data for the application you requested..."

Tags: facebook, roles, facebook-insights

Trying to add an associate as a tester/developer of our application in sandbox mode so they can add the app and test it.  When they go to confirm the developer app request, they get an Application Error dialog box that says:

> There was a problem getting data for the application you requested.
>   The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch.
>   Please try again later.

The app works fine for us in dev mode when authenticating as the administrator, but what do we need to do to add additional users as developers and testers?   The error message is not particularly insightful.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and i solved by temporarily disabling the Sandbox Mode

Comment: hmm, i'll try that but doesn't that make the app accessible publicly? that's not really a viable option except for a quick test.

Comment: Thanks, yes this worked, sorry I missed that you said 'temporarily'.  Disable sandbox to accept the request, then re-enable.  Ahh, facebook.    Lix's group answer is good too, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should try using groups - if you add the desired people to a group and add that group to a "role" in the developers app - there is no confirmation - no questions - no problems :P just gets added and all group members are awarded correct permissions :)
I **really** love that feature!

Answer (score 1):

exit the sandbox mode and then try to accept request. It worked for me. Facebook while accepting the request is looking for available application